Error status 404: No static resource project/api/json/users/save in a Spring Boot project
I have implemented a Spring Boot project:
ETLproject, the application name is ETLprojectApplication.
A POST request in Postman (url: http://localhost:8080/project/api/json/users/save)
releases this error code:
{
    "type": "about:blank",
    "title": "Not Found",
    "status": 404,
    "detail": "No static resource project/api/json/users/save.",
    "instance": "/project/api/json/users/save"
}

the code of pom.xml is the following:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>it.projects</groupId>
    <artifactId>ETLproject</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>H2Project</name>
    <description>H2Project</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

I try to show the structure the project and the relative package:
package dto
JsonPlaceholderUser
package it.projects.SQLserverProject.dto;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.*;


@Data
public class JsonPlaceholderUser {

    private int id;

    private String name;

    private String username;

    private String email;

    private JsonPlaceholderAddress address;

    private String phone;


    private String website;

    private JsonPlaceholderCompany company;

}

package dto
JsonPlaceholderAddress:
package it.projects.SQLserverProject.dto;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.*;

@Data
public class JsonPlaceholderAddress {

    private Integer id;

    private String street;

    private String suite;

    private String city;

    private String zipcode;

    private JsonPlaceholderGeo geo;

    private List<JsonPlaceholderUser> user = new ArrayList<>();
}

package dto
JsonPlaceholderGeo
package it.projects.SQLserverProject.dto;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.*;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.*;
import java.util.*;

@Data
public class JsonPlaceholderGeo {

    private int geo;

    private String lat;

    private String lng;

    private List < JsonPlaceholderAddress > address = new ArrayList<>();
}

package dto
JsonPlaceholderCompany
package it.projects.SQLserverProject.dto;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.*;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.*;
import java.util.*;

@Data
public class JsonPlaceholderCompany {

    private int id;

    private String name;

    private String catchPhrase;

    private String bs;

    private List<JsonPlaceholderUser> user = new ArrayList<>();
}

package entity
ProfileUser
package it.projects.SQLserverProject.entity;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.*;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "userProfile")
public class ProfileUser {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name="street")
    private String street;

    @Column(name="suite")
    private String suite;

    @Column(name="city")
    private String city;

    @Column(name="zipcode")
    private String zipcode;

    @Column(name="phone")
    private String phone;

    @Column(name="website")
    private String website;

    @Column(name="lat")
    private String lat;

    @Column(name="lng")
    private String lng;

    @Column(name="companyName")
    private String companyName;

    @Column(name="companyCatchPhrase")
    private String companyCatchPhrase;

    @Column(name="companyBs")
    private String companyBs;
}

package service
FetchJsonPlaceholderUserService
package it.projects.SQLserverProject.service;

import it.projects.SQLserverProject.dto.*;
import it.projects.SQLserverProject.exception.*;
import it.projects.SQLserverProject.config.*;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.http.*;
import org.springframework.stereotype.*;
import org.springframework.web.client.*;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.*;
import java.util.*;


@Service
public class FetchJsonPlaceholderUserService {

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public List< JsonPlaceholderUser > fetchUserList() {

        String url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";

        // rest call
        ResponseEntity< Object[] > response = restTemplate.getForEntity(url, Object[].class);

        // Tempory Varables
        Object[] objects = response.getBody();

        // Mapping
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        // Return data variables
        try {
            if (objects == null || objects.length == 0) {
                throw new JsonPlaceholderUserListNotFoundException("Json placeholder users list not found");
            }

            List< JsonPlaceholderUser > jsonPlaceholderUserList = new ArrayList<>();

            for (int i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
                jsonPlaceholderUserList.add(mapper.convertValue(objects[i], JsonPlaceholderUser.class));
            }
            return jsonPlaceholderUserList;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        }

    }

    public List< Map< String, Object > > getListPeople() {

        // Build an URL with user id
        String url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/";

        try{
            ResponseEntity< JsonPlaceholderUser[] > response = restTemplate.getForEntity(url, JsonPlaceholderUser[].class);

            // Retrieve the array of users from the response
            Object[] objects = response.getBody();

            // Mapping
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

            // List for containing results
            List <Map <String, Object>> peopleList = new ArrayList<>();

            // Checking if the user list is void
            if (objects == null || objects.length == 0){
                throw new JsonPlaceholderUserListNotFoundException("Json placeholder users list not found");
            }

            // Iterating users
            for (Object obj : objects){

                // Converting the object to a JsonPlaceholderUser
                JsonPlaceholderUser user = mapper.convertValue(obj, JsonPlaceholderUser.class);

                // Mapping for rappresenting the current user
                Map<String, Object> userMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();

                // Adding the name of the user as key
                userMap.put(("id"), user.getId());
                userMap.put("name", user.getName());
                userMap.put("username", user.getUsername());
                userMap.put("email", user.getEmail());
                userMap.put("phone", user.getPhone());
                userMap.put("website", user.getWebsite());

                // Mapping for rappresenting the address user
                Map<String, Object> addressMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
                JsonPlaceholderAddress address = user.getAddress();

                // Adding the user address as key
                addressMap.put(("street"), address.getStreet());
                addressMap.put(("suite"), address.getSuite());
                addressMap.put(("city"), address.getCity());
                addressMap.put(("zipcode"), address.getZipcode());

                // Mapping for rappresenting the geo of the street as key
                Map<String, Object> geoMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
                JsonPlaceholderGeo geo = user.getAddress().getGeo();

                // Adding the street geo as key
                geoMap.put(("lat"), geo.getLat());
                geoMap.put(("lng"), geo.getLng());

                // Mapping for rappresenting the company of the user as key
                Map<String, Object> companyMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
                JsonPlaceholderCompany company = user.getCompany();

                // Adding the company user as key
                companyMap.put(("name"), company.getName());
                companyMap.put(("catchPhrase"), company.getCatchPhrase());
                companyMap.put(("bs"), company.getBs());

                // Adding object maps nested in the user's map

                userMap.put("address", addressMap);
                userMap.put("geo", geoMap);
                userMap.put("company", companyMap);

                // Adding the user map to the results list
                peopleList.add(userMap);

            }
            return peopleList;

        }catch(HttpClientErrorException.NotFound e){
            throw new JsonPlaceholderUserNotFoundException("Failed to fetch users from JSONPlaceholder API", e);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        }
    }

    public JsonPlaceholderUser fetchUserById(int id) {

        // Build an URL with user id
        String url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/" + id;

        try {
            ResponseEntity< JsonPlaceholderUser > response = restTemplate.getForEntity(url, JsonPlaceholderUser.class);

            if (response.getStatusCode().is2xxSuccessful()) {
                return response.getBody();
            } else {
                throw new JsonPlaceholderUserNotFoundException("Json placeholder user with id " + id + " not found");
            }
        } catch (HttpClientErrorException.NotFound e) {
            throw new JsonPlaceholderUserNotFoundException("Json placeholder user with id " + id + " not found", e);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        }

    }

    public List< JsonPlaceholderUser > findUserByName(String name) {

        // Build an URL with user id
        String url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/";

        try {
            ResponseEntity< JsonPlaceholderUser[] > response = restTemplate.getForEntity(url, JsonPlaceholderUser[].class);

            if (response.getStatusCode().is2xxSuccessful()) {
                // Retrieve the array of users from response
                JsonPlaceholderUser[] users = response.getBody();

                // Convert the search name to lowercase
                String searchName = name.toLowerCase();

                // Filter users by name
                List< JsonPlaceholderUser > matchedUsers = new ArrayList<>();
                for (JsonPlaceholderUser user : users) {

                    // Convert the user name to lowercase for case-insensitive comparison
                    String userNameLowerCase = user.getName().toLowerCase();

                    if (userNameLowerCase.contains(searchName)) {
                        matchedUsers.add(user);
                    }
                }
                return matchedUsers;
            } else {
                throw new JsonPlaceholderUserNotFoundException("Failed to fetch users from JSONPlaceholder API");
            }


        } catch (HttpClientErrorException.NotFound e) {
            throw new JsonPlaceholderUserNotFoundException("Failed to fetch users from JSONPlaceholder API\", e");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        }
    }
}

package service
ProfileUserService
package it.projects.SQLserverProject.service;

import it.projects.SQLserverProject.dto.*;
import it.projects.SQLserverProject.repository.*;
import it.projects.SQLserverProject.entity.*;
import it.projects.SQLserverProject.config.*;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.http.*;
import org.springframework.stereotype.*;
import org.springframework.web.client.*;

import java.util.*;

@Service
public class ProfileUserService {

    @Autowired
    private ProfileUserRepository profileUserRepository;

    FetchJsonPlaceholderUserService fetchJsonPlaceholderUserService = new FetchJsonPlaceholderUserService();


    public void saveUsersToProfile() {
        try {
            // Ottieni la lista delle persone dalla chiamata API
            List< Map< String, Object > > peopleList = fetchJsonPlaceholderUserService.getListPeople();

            // Itera attraverso ogni mappa di persona
            for (Map< String, Object > userMap : peopleList) {
                ProfileUser profileUser = new ProfileUser();

                // Imposta i campi del profilo utente dai dati della mappa
                profileUser.setUsername((String) userMap.get("username"));
                profileUser.setEmail((String) userMap.get("email"));
                profileUser.setStreet((String) userMap.get("street"));
                profileUser.setSuite((String) userMap.get("suite"));
                profileUser.setCity((String) userMap.get("city"));
                profileUser.setZipcode((String) userMap.get("zipcode"));
                profileUser.setPhone((String) userMap.get("phone"));
                profileUser.setWebsite((String) userMap.get("website"));
                profileUser.setLat((String) userMap.get("lat"));
                profileUser.setLng((String) userMap.get("lng"));
                profileUser.setCompanyName((String) userMap.get("companyName"));
                profileUser.setCompanyCatchPhrase((String) userMap.get("companyCatchPhrase"));
                profileUser.setCompanyBs((String) userMap.get("companyBs"));

                // Salva il profilo utente nel database
                profileUserRepository.save(profileUser);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        }

    }

}

package repository
ProfileUserRepository
package it.projects.SQLserverProject.repository;

import it.projects.SQLserverProject.dto.*;
import it.projects.SQLserverProject.entity.*;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.*;
import java.util.*;

public interface ProfileUserRepository extends JpaRepository< ProfileUser, Integer> {

}

package config
CustomExceptionHandler
package it.projects.SQLserverProject.config;

import it.projects.SQLserverProject.entity.*;
import it.projects.SQLserverProject.exception.*;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseEntityExceptionHandler;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(DuplicateProductCodeException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<String> handleDuplicateProductCodeException(DuplicateProductCodeException e) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(e.getMessage());
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(ProductIllegalArgumentException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<String> handleProductIllegalArgumentException(ProductIllegalArgumentException e) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(e.getMessage());
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(ProductNotFoundException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<String> handleProductNotFoundException(ProductNotFoundException e) {
        List<Product> emptyProductList = new ArrayList<>();
        emptyProductList.add(new Product());
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body(e.getMessage() + "\n" + emptyProductList);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(ProductSaveException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<String> handleProductSaveException(ProductSaveException e) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(e.getMessage());
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(JsonPlaceholderUserListNotFoundException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<String> handleJsonPlaceholderUserListNotFoundException(JsonPlaceholderUserListNotFoundException e){
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(e.getMessage());
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(JsonPlaceholderUserNotFoundException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<String> handleJsonPlaceholderUserNotFoundException(JsonPlaceholderUserNotFoundException e){
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(e.getMessage());
    }

}

package config
AppConfig
package it.projects.SQLserverProject.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.client.*;

@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }
}

package controller
FetchJsonPlaceholderUserService
package it.projects.SQLserverProject.controller;

import it.projects.SQLserverProject.service.*;
import it.projects.SQLserverProject.dto.*;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.http.*;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.*;
import java.util.*;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/project/api/json")
public class JsonPlaceholderUserController {

    @Autowired
    private FetchJsonPlaceholderUserService fetchJsonPlaceholderUserService;

    @GetMapping(value = "/user/list", produces = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity< ? > getList() throws JsonProcessingException {

        List< JsonPlaceholderUser > jsonList = fetchJsonPlaceholderUserService.fetchUserList();

        return ResponseEntity.accepted().body(jsonList);
    }


    @GetMapping(value = "/user/get/{id}", produces = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public JsonPlaceholderUser getUserById(@PathVariable("id") int id) throws JsonProcessingException {

        JsonPlaceholderUser jsonUser = fetchJsonPlaceholderUserService.fetchUserById(id);
        return jsonUser;
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/user/search/{name}", produces = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity< ? > searchName(@PathVariable("name") String searchName) throws JsonProcessingException {

        List< JsonPlaceholderUser > jsonNameSearch = fetchJsonPlaceholderUserService.findUserByName(searchName);
        return ResponseEntity.accepted().body(jsonNameSearch);
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/user/get/people", produces = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity< ? > getPeople() throws JsonProcessingException{

        List< Map< String, Object > > people = fetchJsonPlaceholderUserService.getListPeople();
        return  ResponseEntity.accepted().body(people);

    }
}

package controller
ProfileUserController
package it.projects.SQLserverProject.controller;

import it.projects.SQLserverProject.service.*;
import it.projects.SQLserverProject.dto.*;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.http.*;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.*;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/project/api/json")
public class ProfileUserController {

    private final ProfileUserService profileUserService;

    @Autowired
    public ProfileUserController(ProfileUserService profileUserService) {
        this.profileUserService = profileUserService;
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/users/save", produces = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<String> saveJsonUser() {
        profileUserService.saveUsersToProfile();
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Users saved to profile successfully");
    }
}

application.yml
# Main Database
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.178.50\SQLEXPRESS:1433;databaseName=ETLprojectDB;encrypt=false
    driverClassName: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
    username: sa
    password: Andreas.1974
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
    hibernate:

      naming:
        physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl

Can you tell me the cause of the error?
Thank you
Andrea

A 404 error means that the app controller can't find the route you are requesting. it looks like you have a route for /project/api/json/users/save, but it's still returning an error. I would try to create a very basic GET route that returns "hello world" or the like to see if it is working.

Also if you are using intelliJ (or maybe Eclipse) you can create a debug point and run your app in debug mode to see what happens.
